# ClassNotFoundException HikariCP with gretty plugin using Jetty 9

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, hikaricp, gretty

I created a Spring demo [web application](https://github.com/wbsouza/demo-spring-cas-pac4j) as a proof of concept. It works fine when I run the class `JettyWrapper` (embedded Jetty). However when I'm trying to run run Jetty 9 using the `gretty` plugin I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` of HikariCP even adding the HikariCP in the plugin classpath.

```java
    jetty.xml config file

    ...
    <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <Arg>
            <New id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
                <Set name="poolName"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.poolName" default="HikariCP"/></Set>
                <Set name="driverClassName"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.driverClassName" default="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.idleTimeout" default="10000"/></Set>
                <Set name="maximumPoolSize"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.maximumPoolSize" default="5"/></Set>
                <Set name="username"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.username" default="SA"/></Set>
                <Set name="password"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.password" default=""/></Set>
                <Set name="jdbcUrl"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.jdbcUrl" default="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/demodb"/></Set>
                <Set name="connectionTestQuery"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.connectionTestQuery" default="SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE"/></Set>
                <Set name="connectionInitSql"><SystemProperty name="hikaricp.connectionInitSql" default="SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE"/>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
    ...


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$configure.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurerImpl.applyJettyXml(JettyConfigurerImpl.groovy:64)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurer$applyJettyXml$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone can help with any tips and/or directions will be greatly appreciated.

**EDITED:** *After I got this problem solved, I found a new problem related what made me [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177905/how-to-configure-gradle-to-add-a-resource-directory-on-the-gretty-classloader). In that case I had some extra resources to be added in the classpath (configs dir) and I spent a couple hours until I found a non documented feature. Now everything is working fine.*

Answer (score 2):

How are you adding the library to Gretty classpath?

I've done something similar with this line in my gradle.build:

`dependencies {
   ///...
   gretty 'my:library:version'
}`

And it worked great

http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Servlet-container-classpath.html

By the way, I'm also using HikariCP in a web app launched by Gretty, but in my case I'm instantiating the pool programatically, and the Hikari library is in the webapp classpath, not in the container's.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it.

Comment: the `gretty` dependency works fine for me, thanks for you help

Comment: The good thing to use a conection pool in the container is it can be shared across the webapps via `JNDI`, consequently optimizing the database connections. I have more than one webapp using the same database and in my case it seems more appropriated.