# Adding a resource directory to classpath of greety (Gradle Plugin)

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, build.gradle, gretty

I'm trying to run `gradle` with the plugin `gretty` using `jetty`. The problem is the `gretty` plugin does put the directory `src/test/resources` on the `classpath` and I need a *lazy load* for some *.properties* files on the `Jetty` startup.

```java
dependencies {
    gretty "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:${version_hikaricp}"
    gretty "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:${version_hsqldb}"
    gretty files("target/classes/main", "target/resources/main", "src/test/resources")
}
```

The code above is not loading the resources to the `classpath` to be used by the `gretty` plugin. When we run `Jetty` we can add our resource files on `${JETTY_BASE}/resources` and those files will be present in our `classpath`. Any idea/trick to get the same feature with `gretty`plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution looking into the [`gretty` opened issues](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/86). According to the author, this is a feature not documented yet. Here is the solution:

```
 gretty {
     classPath ['src/test/resources', 'src/main/configs']
 }
```